# Getting error while running perl module from command line

Tags: perl, command-line, perl-module

I have a customized perl module(*Modulehere*) that take xls sheet and parsing it.

I tried to run that from commandline itself like:

```
 perl -I /home/suser/modules -e "use Modulehere;Modulehere::load_it('/tmp/test.xls')"
```

But it gives the error like:

```
Can't open perl script "–e": No such file or directory
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly the command you typed?  Although you could use `-MModulehere` to avoid the `use Modulehere;` part of the command, that is not a part of your problem.

Comment: Are you sure it is perl that you are running? Try `perl --help` and `which perl` maybe you're running some kind of wrapper script.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machines (OS X and Linux) but looking at the documentation (`man perlrun`)

> ```
>    -Idirectory
>         Directories specified by -I are prepended to the search path for modules (@INC).
> ```

There is no space between `-I` and the directory. **Maybe** your Perl version is being to strict and considering everything after the space as a script file.